# using variable in scss doesn't work for vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, styling

I am working on the vue component, which has applied scss for styling.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
:root {
    --c-text-primary: #282a32;
    --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--c-background-secondary);
    color: var(--c-text-primary);
}
</style>
```

however it doesn't work out, any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Remove 'scoped' from the style tag.

Comment: thanks, scoped is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sass dependencies installed?

I have the dependencies:

- sass
- sass-loader

and it works fine for me